# Why are we forced to use double-angle identity to integrate $(\cos(x))^2$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

All the videos I have watched to help me solve this question, they all start off by using the double angle identity of:
$$\cos^2(x) = \frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$$
Yet no one explains why.
Can't we use the substitution method by saying:
$$u = \cos(x)$$

Comment: It works because it works and not because we are forced to use it.

Comment: @KurtG. I understand that. But can the substitution method be used?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: This identity looks [wrong](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/javlklk0os).

Comment: @KurtG. Missing a square on the first.

Comment: It is much easier but nobody would oblige you to use ti

Comment: If you want to know more about integrating with trigonometric substitutions, I suggest you read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5):

Technically, you can integrate by parts.

$\int(\cos^2x)dx=\int(\cos x)[(\cos x)dx]$

$=\int(\cos x)d(\sin x)$

$=\sin x\cos x-\int(\sin x)d(\cos x)+C$

$=\sin x\cos x+\int(\sin^2x)dx+C$

$=x+\sin x\cos x-\int(\cos^2x)dx+C$ (using $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$)

So

$\int(\cos^2x)dx=x+\sin x\cos x-\int(\cos^2x)dx+C$

and the like integrals may be combined and solved giving

$\int(\cos^2x)dx=\frac12(x+\sin x\cos x+C).$

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on substitution, here is one way.

Let $t = \cos x$.

$x=\arccos t$

$\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$

$\begin{align}
\int\cos^2 x \mathrm dx=\int \frac{-t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\mathrm dt
\end{align}$

Then we use integration by parts: $u=t, v'=-t(1-t^2)^{-1/2}$

$\begin{align}
\int\cos^2 x \mathrm dx&=t\sqrt{1-t^2}-\int\sqrt{1-t^2} \mathrm dt\\
&=(\cos x)(\sin x)-\int\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}(-\sin x)\mathrm dx\\
&=(\cos x)(\sin x)+\int(1-\cos^2 x)\mathrm dx\\
&=(\cos x)(\sin x)+x-\int\cos^2 x\mathrm dx\\
\end{align}$

Then move the $\int\cos^2x\mathrm dx$ from RHS to LHS, then divide both sides by $2$.

$\begin{align}
\therefore \int\cos^2 x \mathrm dx&=\frac12 ((\cos x)(\sin x)+x)+c\\
&=\frac14\sin 2x+\frac{x}{2}+c 
\end{align}$

Now you can see why using the double angle identity is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative method is to solve a linear system:
$$I=\int \cos^2 x \,\mathrm d x \quad \quad J=\int \sin^2 x \,\mathrm d x$$
You can compute $I+J$ and $I-J$, then solve for $I$.

Comment: beautiful, our instructor taught this a long time ago, Thanks for reminding